# SwiftUI DatePicker in Form shows different text randomly

Tags: datepicker, swiftui, swiftui-form

I am trying to use DatePicker in my app. After I select a date, the displayed text changes randomly. it changes on random dates too.
Sometimes it shows date like "Jan 26, 2021" and sometimes it shows "1/28/2021".

Can someone please help me find a solution here ?
I want to show something like "Jan 26, 2021" if that date is selected.

Here is how it works right now
[image]

Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeirdDate: View {
    @State var selectedDate : Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Text("Testing out Date")
                DatePicker(
                    "Date: ",
                    selection: $selectedDate,
                    displayedComponents: [.date]
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WeirdDate_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WeirdDate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can confirm, reproducible in simulator, iOS 14.3, Xcode 12.3. Clearly a bug, worth submitting to Apple.

Comment: There is a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090210/swiftui-datepicker-jumps-between-short-and-medium-date-formats-when-changing-the