# SwiftUI DatePicker jumps between short and medium date formats when changing the date

Tags: ios, swiftui

(Using Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14.3)

I use a `DatePicker` component with the default style (`DefaultDatePickerStyle`) to display and edit a date: the component shows the current date value in a label and pops up a calendar when tapping that label. So far, so good.

When I change the date (either programmatically or manually it in the UI), the component erratically changes the date format of its label. It seems to switch between the `.short` and `.medium` values of `DateFormatter.Style`. Note that the date format cannot be set programmatically, it's internal to `DatePicker`.

Here is an example:

[image: Date format changes when altering the date]

The `DatePicker` displays "Feb 7, 2021"; I alter the date by subtracting one day using a button, causing the component to display "2/6/21"; subtracting a day again, the display changes to "Feb 5, 2021" etc. Sometimes it keeps the same format for a few dates, but mostly it toggles on every change.

Example code:

```swift
struct DateView: View {
  @State var date = Date()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
      Button("-1 day") {
        date.addTimeInterval(-24*60*60)
      }
      Button("+1 day") {
        date.addTimeInterval(24*60*60)
      }
      DatePicker(
        "Date",
        selection: $date,
        displayedComponents: .date
      ).labelsHidden()
    }
  }
}
```

Omitting `displayedComponents` or `labelsHidden` has no effect on the issue.

The same issue can be observed when repeatedly opening the calendar popup and selecting dates: after closing the popup, the displayed date sometimes is in short format, and sometimes in medium format.

Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: I would file feedback with Apple. Seems like a bug.

Comment: @nicksarno yep already did that, thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @NorNewman unfortunately not. My workaround is to manually display the date in a `Text` using a custom `DateFormatter`, and when the user taps the text I toggle display of a `DatePicker` with `WheelDatePickerStyle`. This works reliably, even though I would have liked to use the new picker UI.

Comment: @dr_barto have you received a response from Apple? Could you link the bug here please? I am experiencing this exact bug with my app.

Comment: @dsynkd here's the link: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8995970; so far Apple only asked me to test this in Xcode 13 Beta, where the problem still occurred.

Comment: This bug still exists on iOS 16 beta1, filed FB10212223

Comment: 24*60*60 is not 1 day!

Comment: Still a bug on iOS 16.4...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Here is a found workaround (tested with Xcode 13beta / iOS 15)

[image: demo]

```
  DatePicker(
    "Date",
    selection: $date,
    displayedComponents: .date
  )
  .labelsHidden()
  .id(date)             // << here !!
```

Comment: You are forcing it to **rebuild** on any change of the date!

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Sure, but it's not a big deal, DatePicker is really easy to rebuild

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, of course - it's by the purpose

Comment: Brilliant solution for a really stupid bug. It has been in there for awhile, glad I found this workaround.

Comment: I have another problem, every time I select date or month or year, the picker closes automatically.. anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: I suggest to keep the .id() as unique and it will work.. but if you keep date as id the date will keep changing and that will lead to view closing and also redrawing.. hope this helps someone.

Comment: Using .id(UUID()) worked for me, instead of the date value. What a headache...

Comment: I find this makes it worse for me on iOS 16.5. What an infuriating bug.

Comment: No luck on iOS 17.

Comment: No luck on iOS 17.2

Answer (score 5):

For me, the suggested workaround did work, but the date was still showing the short format for a very short moment before formatting the correct way. Another approch, which works without any issues for me, is to wrap a `UIDatePicker` to use it in SwiftUI instead of using the build in view (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853272/13440564).

```swift
struct MyDatePicker: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var date: Date
    var range: ClosedRange<Date>

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIDatePicker {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.changed(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        datePicker.minimumDate = range.lowerBound
        datePicker.maximumDate = range.upperBound
        return datePicker
    }

    func updateUIView(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker, context: Context) {
        datePicker.date = date
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MyDatePicker.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(date: $date)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private let date: Binding<Date>

        init(date: Binding<Date>) {
            self.date = date
        }

        @objc func changed(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
            self.date.wrappedValue = sender.date
        }
    }
}
```

You can the simply call it like this and customize it to your needs:

```swift
HStack {
    Text("Select date")

    Spacer()

    MyDatePicker(
        date: $date,
        range: range
    ).frame(maxHeight: 35)
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me. For me, the bug is happening when I use `Calendar.current.date` to initialize the bound variable by subtracting days from the current date.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works on iOS 15+ (as tested)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to bind `DatePicker` to a date on a Core Data `NSManagedObject`, and I'm showing a calendar pop-up like this:

[image: DatePicker lozenge with a calendar selector popup.]

The other SwiftUI solution (recommending `.id(date)`) didn't work for me, instead the popup behaved strangely and disappeared on every second tap.

What I've done instead is to put the date into a state variable:

```
    @State private var snoozeUntilDate = Date()
```

And initialise this variable to the managed object's date whenever the date picker is shown:

```
DatePicker("Snooze until date", selection: $snoozeUntilDate, displayedComponents: .date)
    .labelsHidden()
    .onAppear {
        snoozeUntilDate = task.snoozeUntilDate!
    }
```

And update the managed object whenever the `@State` variable changes:

```
    .onChange(of: snoozeUntilDate) { newDate in
        task.snoozeUntilDate = newDate
    }
```

Doing this has fixed the problem for me!

While I'm not 100% sure, I think the trouble here might have been caused by the managed object. I tried making the `@State` variable optional (`Date?`), and that didn't re-introduce the weirdness, so it seems like the binding to the managed object (which I was creating using `Binding(task.snoozeUntilDate)!`) might have been the source of the weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of using `.id` to force the date picker to re-draw does not work consistently in my experience, and is a bit of a hack.

I've spent some time looking into this and the source of this bug appears to be with how the `DatePicker` picks up the current locale, which is how it determines the date format.

I've had more success explicitly setting the locale using the environment modifier:

```swift
DatePicker().environment(\.locale, .current)
```

Its not perfect - I still sometimes see it briefly show a shorter date format before showing the correct format.

If you don't want to hardcode the date picker to a specific locale (even the `.current` one), I recommend you add a property to your view that picks up the current locale from the environment:

```
@Environment(\.locale) private var locale
```

And then pass that in instead - this will still enable you to override the locale higher up the view hierarchy if needed.

Another thing to note about the `.id` hack is it changes the behaviour of the date picker - the default behaviour in compact style is for the popover calendar to remain visible unless the user explicitly dismisses it by tapping outside once they are happy with their selection. The `.id` modifier causes the picker to re-draw and the popover to close immediately.

Comment: Didn't work for me.