# datepicker formatting on displaying date

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui

Hello after updating to Xcode 14 I'm facing with an issue on date picker so when I pick some date sometime date would be formatted like:
**25 sep 2022 other times 30/09/2022**
in Xcode 13 it was working fine

```
DatePicker("transactionDate", selection: $vm.transactionDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
.labelsHidden()
.id(vm.transactionDate)
.onChange(of: vm.transactionDate) { date in
 vm.selectedEndRecurrenceDate = date
}
}
.datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
```

So I don't understand now how to fix, nothing is changed in the code

Comment: Could you describe what you mean with _other times_, is it for other users or something else that differs between each occasion it changes? Can you reproduce this?

Comment: It differs each time I choose a new date with the picker change the format seams randomly

Comment: how do you display the date? Dates are formatted when you display it, otherwise 
it is just `A specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone.`. Show a reproducible example code, so we can test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an `.id()` modifier to your picker was a workaround for an old bug, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090210/swiftui-datepicker-jumps-between-short-and-medium-date-formats-when-changing-the)

When testing this in Xcode 14.1 beta (iOS) in the simulator I can reproduce the issue when I have the `id` modifier *but as soon as I remove it the picker works fine*

So it seems the hack to workaround the previous bug now creates a bug! So simply remove the `.id()` modifier since it isn't useful here.

```
DatePicker("transactionDate", selection: $vm.transactionDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
    .labelsHidden()
    .onChange(of: vm.transactionDate) { date in
        vm.selectedEndRecurrenceDate = date
    }
}
.datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
```

Comment: oh great, infact in xcode 13 it do the same thing as now but with id it fixed